# Mysql command via shell_exec, only the first one works

Tags: php, mysql, shell-exec

I need to run several sql command via shell_exec.
The first one works perfectly, but not the others.

I echoed the command ran by shell_exec, and those command works in terminal.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
$test1 = shell_exec('sudo mysql -u root -e "create database '.$name_db.';"');

$test2 = shell_exec('sudo mysql -u root -e "create user '.$user_db.'@localhost identified by '.$pass_db.';"');

$test3 = shell_exec('sudo mysql -u root -e "grant all privileges on '.$name_db.'.* to \''.$user_db.'\'@localhost;"');

$test4 = shell_exec('sudo mysql -u root -e "flush privileges";');

$test5 = shell_exec("sudo zcat $path_db_zip | mysql -u root $name_db");
```

All "$test*" print 'NULL'.

Comment: `create database '.$user_db.'@localhost identified...` is incorrect. You're trying to create a user, not a database

Comment: But i just figured out that it was already `create user ...`, i put `create database...` when i prepared the code to post it here.
So my question is still on !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to put it in a sh file and send it as a parameter.

```
cat  "mysql -u root -e create database `$1`;create user `$2`@`localhost identified by $3; grant all privileges on `$1` to `$2`@`localhost` with grant option; flush privileges;" > /addMysql.sh
```

then run shel_exec( sudo /addMysql.sh $db $username $password)

I didn't test it but you can do it like this.

Comment: I modified a bit your code, but this is working now, thanks !
The only thing that doesn't work at the moment is the last line, when i want to import sql to my database.
It works via the terminal, but doesn't work while running in .sh file

Comment: You should add the following at the end of the file and send the filename as a parameter to the sh file. Or you want to use this : echo "mysql -u root $1 < $2" >>  /addMysql.sh

Comment: mysql -u root $1 < $3

Comment: I have this in my file :

sudo mysql -u root -e "create database $1;"
sudo mysql -u root -e "create user $2@localhost identified by '$3';"
sudo mysql -u root -e "grant all privileges on $1.* to $2@localhost;"
sudo mysql -u root -e "flush privileges;"
sudo zcat $4 | mysql -u root $1


I send the path of the file as a parameter just like other data. The error says "Incorrect database name"
I also tried mysql -u root $1 < $3, but doesn't work neither.

Comment: You should use the EOF strategy when using cat or zcat-like code. Your script should be "mysql -u root $1 $4" instead of "sudo zcat $4 | mysql -u root $1" and a file like $4 /tmp/importdb.sql. If you want, you can pass your variable to the sql script shell_exec before running this script.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I just noticed that there were invisble character (^M) at the end of each line in the .sh file. And those character made it going wrong.